# How to customize the approval button on the Expense Claim screen

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I am trying to customize the approve button and I can't find the right method to do it.

Could you tell me how I can manipulate that event.

Thanks in advance.

[button to customize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgvtG.png)

[Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEaAN.png)

Answer (score 0):

I looked around at the ExpenseClaimEntry, and the approval is added from the class ExpenceClaimApproval. You can browse the code through the Code Library in an extension Library under the folder App_Data\CodeRepository\PX.Objects\EP\ExpenseClaimEntry.cs. The derived type is declared in the Descriptor\Attribute.cs file. There is a StatusHandler you can set that is executed upon approval/denial.

I built this test graph and was able to break in the middle of the approval process:

```
public class ExpenseClaimEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<ExpenseClaimEntry>
{
    public void CustomApprovalAction(EPExpenseClaim item)
    {
        //do something
    }

    public override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
        Base.Approval.StatusHandler += CustomApprovalAction;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have reviewed the code and I get an error in StatusHandler